# How to capture the ngxchart in angular as an image

Tags: angular

In my `bar-chart` component if I have a chart like:

```
<ngx-charts-bar-vertical  [showDataLabel]="true" [results]="data" [xAxis]="true"
                          [yAxis]="true" [legend]="false" [showXAxisLabel]="false"
                          [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel" [showYAxisLabel]="true"
                          [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel">
</ngx-charts-bar-vertical>
```

And I'm using this in another component with its selector like:

```
<app-barchart id="toCapture"></app-barchart>
```

Now I want to capture the chart using `dom-to-image` library so I tried this:

```
capture() {
  const chartElement = document.getElementById('toCapture');
  domtoimage.toPng(chartElement).then((dataUrl) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = dataUrl;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
  });
}
```

Even if I place the id to the `ngx-charts-bar-vertical` tag it isn't working when I inspect I can see the image tag but there's no content inside the image, how can I fix this?

**UPDATE**

If I use `setTimeout` and call `capture` after 1 sec then it's working but I don't want to use setTimeout and also I want to place the id to the selector tag.